# (SOLVED) Permanent nVidia Powermizer Performance Mode

Tags: release-loki, graphic-drivers, nvidia

anyone found a way to keep nVidia's Powermizer settings to stick to **Performance Mode** between computer restarts?

If I select it from nVidia Settings GUI it always reverts to **Auto Mode** between computer restarts.

I want it to stay in **Performance Mode**.

Already tried adding options to device section of the xorg.conf:

> ```
> Section "Device"
>     Identifier "nvidia"
>     Driver "nvidia"
>     BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
>     Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
>     Option  "Coolbits" "13"
>     Option  "RegistryDwords" "PowerMizerEnable=0x1; PerfLevelSrc=0x2222; PowerMizerDefaultAC=0x1"
> EndSection
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a **workaround**:

Changing performance modes is possible through terminal with the following command:

```
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1
```

where:

0 - adaptive mode

1 - max performance mode

2 - auto mode

Now you can just create a small startup script (like for many workarounds in Linux). Just create a *yourscriptname*.desktop file under ~/.config/autostart and fill it with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=powermizer-maxperformance-autostart
Comment=Ustawiamy GPU na poziomie najwyższej wydajności
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=5
```

To test if it is actually working open nVidia Settings GUI and check Powermizer.

Alternatively issue a command in the terminal and check the output:

```
nvidia-smi --query-gpu=pstate --format=csv
```

P0 - max performance

...

P12 - min performance